# Yii dynamic dropdown output to view

Tags: php, ajax, yii

Using this [wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/creating-a-dependent-dropdown/) I have a dynamic dropdownlist working just fine.  Instead of the related data populating another dropdownlist I just want all the related values to display at once on the screen in some sort of formatted list.

I changed the update in the ajax action to `'update'=>'#cities',` and added to my view...

```
<div id="cities"> 
   <?php echo $model->relatedCities; ?>
</div
```

and to my model

```
public function getRelatedCities()
{
   $out=CHtml::listData($this->cities,'CityId','Name');
   return implode('<br />', $out);
}
```

When I make my selection in my dropdownlist nothing is updated in `<div id="cities">` and the ajax call in firebug looks fine.

So how can I display the dynamic related content from the dropdownlist all at once?

Comment: Might be wrong, but shouldn't `$model->relatedCities` be `$model->RelatedCities`?

Comment: No that is not a factor here.

Comment: Have you confirmed that $out is actually returning something?

Comment: try my solution below, it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with your action, you have to `echo` instead of `return`.

Because your ajax call is expecting html data, and not some string.

So try this:

```
public function getRelatedCities()
{
 $out=CHtml::listData($this->cities,'CityId','Name');
 echo implode('<br />', $out);
}
```

p.s: Assuming that you have verified that $out is not empty.

Comment: ask for clarifications if needed.